# Installshield 11.5: How to implement browse file functionality?

Tags: installshield

I am trying to implement browse button with its adjacent edit box in Installshield 11.5. Unfortunately version 11.5 does not have standard controls for this. Is there a simple workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield encompasses many technologies. What project type are you using?

For Basic MSI, you could look at the CustomSetup dialog and observe how it uses the BrowseDialog property to associate INSTALLDIR to the Modal File Browser dialog.